# convert the following code from a for-loop to Array#map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, backbone.js

i am working on simple js function... 
I am trying to convert the following code from a for-loop to Array#map
providing my code below in the fiddle.. 
bnasically i am trying to learn array map..

http://jsfiddle.net/newtdms2/

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {
    var result = [];
    result = numbers.map(function(num) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            result.push(numbers[i] * 2)
        }
        return result;
    });
}

module.exports = doubleAll
```

Comment: `module.exports = (nums) => nums.map(x => 2*x)` - that's your whole code with new node (with arrows) and `map`

Answer (score 1):

Your for inside `map` is not required:

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {
    var result = [];
    result = numbers.map(function(num) {
        return (num * 2);
    });
   return result;
}
```

And simpler can be:

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {    
   return numbers.map(function(num) {
      return (num * 2);
   });
}
```

**Array.prototype.map:** will loop once through each element in an array. It receives a callback function as the argument and the callback function takes three arguments, being the first 2:

- `currentItem:` The element being processed in the array in the example above `num`.
- `index:` The index of the element being processed in the array, in for loop this will be `i`.

Comment: Why the `result`? You're allocating an array here for no real reason

Comment: `result` was kept in the first sample to avoid major differences from the sample post and highlight the missing return but later it is explained how it can be simplified. But it is all for the sake of simplicity a more clear answer

Comment: *Now* our answers are the same :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a `for` loop in your `map`, map will call the function callback on each element of the array you pass as parameter. So just try something like :

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {
  return numbers.map(function (num) {
    return num * 2;
  });
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the doc for the map method, could be interesting to you !

Comment: Same as my answer presented first

Comment: You rushed the thing. Yes our codes are almost the same, but I took more time to **explain** at least what I've done, since that's what the OP wants. I've just changed my answer with the help of @BenjaminGruenbaum.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {
  return numbers.map(num => num*2);
}
```